# Creating a Landmine - PYTHON

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm trying to create a landmine for my game, I would like the player after placing it could view the radius of impact. This way I have been trying to get a python code that activates the `show_physics_visualization` button on a single object.
I Tried:

```
Import bpy
Bpy..data.scene ["Scene"] game_settings.show_physics_visualization (True)
```

My mine object is called MineForce.
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: that will not work, period. First the physics visualization is a toggle, game wide. second `bpy` is blender's api, that will do nothing in a running game. `bge` is the api for the game engine.

Comment: Create another object to be the child of the mine that shows the blast radius. Maybe a shapekey could show/hide the display mesh if it was part of the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above:

- Show Physics Visualization is for debugging purposes - and should not be part of the game.
- Range indicators are part of your game. You can present them as you like. For example a cone with wireframe material would provide you the look you are looking for.